# vowell or consonant function

Tags: javascript

I am making a javascript function that tell the user whether the letter they entered is a vowel or consonant. I have tried to make a function but without success. Please someone show whats going on and how to fix it.

Many Thanks

James

```js
function letter() {

    var
    let = prompt("Your Letter");

    if (let == 'a' ||
      let == 'e' ||
      let == 'i' ||
      let == 'o' ||
      let == 'u') {

      alert("Your letter is a vowel");

    } else {

      alert("Your letter is a consonant");
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script>
    function letter() {

        var
        let = prompt("Your Letter");

        if (let == 'a' ||
          let == 'e' ||
          let == 'i' ||
          let == 'o' ||
          let == 'u') {

          alert("Your letter is a vowel");

        } else {

          alert("Your letter is a consonant");
        }​
  </script>

</head>
<h3>Vowel or Consonant</h3> 
<input id="prompt" type="text" />
<p id="answer"></p>
<button onclick="letter()">Check letter</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the output?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani what do you mean by that? sorry im new to JS. :)

Comment: Check my answer :) Copy that code and it will work. Its exactly as yours with some corrections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the dev tools and see what the console tells you.

I see three mistakes :

- you're missing a closing `}` bracket at the end of the function.
- you're using the reserved word `let` as a variable name. Say you use `letter` instead. JS engines may find their way out of your `let`, but it's bad practice anyway. Besides, since you renamed `let` to `letter`, you may want to rename your function to something that actually means what it does, such as `displayPromptLetterType`.
- The way to retrieve the user's input from the field near the button is `var letter = document.getElementById("prompt").value;`

Besides, rather than a long `if` condition, you may want it a tad more data driven :

```
    var vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"];
    if (vowels.indexOf(letter.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
       ...
```

Comment: A simpler way is vowels.includes(letter.toLowerCase())

Comment: That's so 2022 !

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way to **Iterate over Strings** will be to:

```
const myText = 'my word';

for (const myVariable of myText) {
  console.log(myVariable);
}

=> m
=> y 
=> 
=> w
=> o
=> r
=> d
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Answer (score 0):

You just missed to add '**}**' at the end of your function.  You are closing IF but not your function

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script>
    function letter() {

        var leta = prompt("Your Letter");

        if (leta == 'a' ||
          leta == 'e' ||
          leta == 'i' ||
          leta == 'o' ||
          leta == 'u') {

          alert("Your letter is a vowel");

        } else {

          alert("Your letter is a consonant");
        }
    }
  </script>

</head>
<h3>Vowel or Consonant</h3> 
<input id="prompt" type="text" />
<p id="answer"></p>
<button onclick="letter()">Check letter</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on your code and @Mathias Dolidon suggestions. With this example you can determine if input is a vowel or not, but you must check if it is a letter before say any non-vowel is a consonant.

```js
(function() {
  var vowels = [
    "a", "á", "à", "ä", "â",
    "e", "é", "è", "ë", "ê",
    "i", "í", "ì", "ï", "î",
    "o", "ó", "ò", "ö", "ô",
    "u", "ú", "ù", "ü", "û"
  ];

  function isVowel(letter) {
    return vowels.indexOf(letter.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  }

  function getLetterType() {
    var input = $("#prompt").val();
    var $answer = $("#answer");
    if (input.length > 0) {
      $answer.text(isVowel(input) ? "Your input is a vowel" : "Your input is not a vowel");
    } else {
      $answer.text("Insert one character.");
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#check-letter").on("click", getLetterType);
  });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Vowel or Consonant</h3> 
<input id="prompt" type="text" size="1" maxlength="1" />
<p id="answer"></p>
<button id="check-letter">Check letter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {

    for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
      if(s[i]==='a'||s[i]==='e'||s[i]==='i'||s[i]==='o'||s[i]==='u'){
    console.log(s[i]);
    }
    }
    for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
      if(s[i]!=='a'&&s[i]!=='e'&&s[i]!=='i'&&s[i]!=='o'&&s[i]!=='u'){
    console.log(s[i]);
    } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy approach that I came up with.

```
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
for(var vowel in s){
    var array = s.split('');
}

for(var char of array){
    const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    if(vowels.includes(char))
        console.log(char);
}

for(var char of array){
    const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    if(vowels.includes(char) == 0)
        console.log(char);
}
```

}

Upvote if it helped!