# Check if is vowel or consonant

Tags: javascript

i just want to develop my thinking logic in pure js. The problem is that when i run the script in the console with the help node.js, it shows me for each iteration. Vowel and consonants. But i just need to write in console only once. Maybe, i should save result in a separate variable after the entire list of vowels? But i don't how to do, Below is the code:

```
// problem who i can't do
function letter(arg) {
    var vowel = "aeouiAEOUI";
    var result = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < vowel.length; i++) {
        if(arg === vowel[i]) {
            console.log("vowel");
        } else {
            console.log("consonant");
        }
    }
}
```

i found resolved task on the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641249/javascript-vowell-or-consonant-function). But i don't understand why ? arg >= 0 ?

```
function letter_indexof(arg) {
    var vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]; 
    if(vowels.indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
        console.log("vowel");
    } else {
        console.log("consonant");
    }   
}
```

i will be grateful to all for help.

Comment: what is your expectation? input 1 character, and show vowel or consonant?

Comment: `arg >= 0` because if the character does not match then `.indexOf()` will return `-1`

Comment: Sorry i try now to understand. I think have need to something time  for understand.( blushing ) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tweak your current code, you can have a variable which indicates whether the character is a consonant, and starts out as `true`, and if you find a vowel, reassign it to `false`, then check that variable:

```js
function letter(arg) {
  var vowel = "aeouiAEOUI";
  var result = "";
  let isConsonant = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < vowel.length; i++) {
    if (arg === vowel[i]) {
      isConsonant = false;
    }
  }
  if (isConsonant) {
    console.log("consonant");
  } else {
    console.log("vowel");
  }
}

letter('a');
letter('f');
```

You could also log and `return` immediately when finding a vowel:

```js
function letter(arg) {
  var vowel = "aeouiAEOUI";
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < vowel.length; i++) {
    if (arg === vowel[i]) {
      console.log("vowel");
      return;
    }
  }
  console.log("consonant");
}

letter('a');
letter('f');
```

It would be easier to use a regular expression, though:

```js
const letter = arg => console.log(
  /[aeiou]/i.test(arg) ? 'vowel' : 'consonant'
);

letter('a');
letter('f');
```